# PHP script memory leak issue

Tags: php, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I'm running the PHP code below from command line. The issue is, its memory consumption far more than what it should be. I can't, for the life of me, figure out where the memory is getting consumed.

```
for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++)  
        {
            $classObject = $classObjects[$i];                       

            echo $i . "   :   " . memory_get_usage(true) . "\n";
            $classDOM = $scraper->scrapeClassInfo($classObject,$termMap,$subjectMap);           
            unset($classDOM);           
        }
```

According to me, the memory consumed by my script should remain more or less constant after every iteration of the loop. Any memory consumed by `$scraper->scrapeClassInfo()` should be freed when its members go out of scope.

This is the output file I get. For the sake of brevity, I'm showing every 10th line of the output:

```
0   :   5767168
10   :   12058624
20   :   18350080
30   :   24903680
40   :   30932992
50   :   37748736
60   :   43778048
70   :   49807360
80   :   55836672
90   :   62914560
97   :   66846720

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 44 bytes) in /home/content/60/8349160/html/drexel/simple_html_dom.php on line 1255
```

Finally, as far as I can see, what `$scraper->scrapeClassInfo()` is doing should not really be the culprit, but just in case, here is the code:

```
function scrapeClassInfo($class,$termMap,$subjectMap)
        {
            $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
            $ckfile2 = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE2");
            $ckfile3 = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE3");         

            $termpage = $termMap[$class['termcode']];
            $subjectpage = $subjectMap[$class['subjectcode']];
            $classpage = $class['classlink'];

            //hit the main page and get cookie
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->mainURL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            //hit the term page and get cookie
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $termpage);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            //hit the subject page and get cookie
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile3);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $subjectpage);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            //hit the class page and scrape
            $ch = curl_init();              
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile3);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $classpage);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return str_get_html($result);
        }
```

The method called in the last line, `str_get_html()` is a member of [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Should it matter, this is how I am calling my script:

`/usr/local/php5/bin/php index.php 2>&1 1>output`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, figured it out. Apparently, its a bug that all version of PHP prior to 5.3 suffer from. Setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` causes massive memory leaks.

I ran the script again, this time invoking the php 5.3 binary:

```
/web/cgi-bin/php5_3 index.php 2>&1 1>output
```

And the output file reads:

```
0   :   6291456
10   :   9437184
20   :   10747904
30   :   11534336
40   :   11534336
50   :   11534336
60   :   11534336
70   :   11534336
80   :   11534336
90   :   11534336
99   :   11534336
152.74998211861 sec
```

Now that's what I'm talking about! Perfectly constant memory footprint.

Comment: When I wrote "Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true" I meant to write "Setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true causes massive memory leaks". Edited.

Comment: Huh! So it definitely wasn't `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217238/php-curl-memory-leak-when-using-curlopt-ssl-verifypeer-true)

Comment: @AdamMonsen: Can't say for sure what CURL option was causing it. Switching to the 5.3 binary fixed the problem.

Comment: Ok, interesting. I'm easily able to repro https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61030 on RHEL 6, but not on any Ubuntu. Both have PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following in your code.

1. **Remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)` as you are not capturing it.**
2. **Do not close curl handle. Reuse it.**

As a current workaround you can run the php script with higher `memroy_limit`

```
 $ php -d memory_limit=1G /path/to/script
```

1G means 1 Gigabyte.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely in the right direction. I did try removing `CUROPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, but in the last curl request I make, I needed to leave it and so I still had the memory issue. Anyways, see my answer below.